# how are cookies retrieved from itms links stored?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, safari

I have an app where we are using wireless distribution to install for our beta users. the install/upgrade links use the form: `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=`

the apache server we're hosting the app at is protected via a cookie based authentication mechanism. our basic problem is that although our authentication mechanism is issuing a delete for the cookie in question, it seems that itms (or possibly safari) on the device is not respecting this delete, because subsequent requests contain the *original cookie*. weird.

my question is, what is actually persisting cookies for itms links opened from safari? safari itself? or itms on the device?

I can't find any documentation on this so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: did you have any progress on this issue? i'm having similar problems...

Comment: no progress, I think it's a real bug.

Comment: We're seeing this too only we're using SiteMinder to provide the authentication/authorization.  Its reporting that subsequent visits using the itms-services link have expired cookies and this is keeping our users from being able to re-download apps.  Need a way to delete or be able to update/refresh these cookies in the installer's user-agent (not Safari).

Comment: By the way, there is an Apple Support thread related to this issue and in that thread, there is a reference to a bugreport ticket created with Apple where Apple may have responded a classification of "serious bug".  https://discussions.apple.com/message/17610099#17610099

Comment: From my research, it seems that the installer uses a different user-agent on the device (ie, not Safari) and as you said, it is not responding to delete-cookie commands and is not allowing the cookie to be refreshed.  Since the installer is using a different user-agent, deleting the cookies within Safari doesn't help.

Comment: scottcher, this makes a lot of sense because in practice, deleting the cookies in safari indeed does nothing. we were quite lucky that we used enterprise distribution for beta testers only.

Answer (score 0):

ScottCher, you're right. From the access log, the itms-services agent looks like:

> iTunes-iPad-M/5.1.1+(2;+16GB;+dt:75)

while Safari agent is:

> Mozilla/5.0+(iPad;+CPU+OS+5_1_1+like+Mac+OS+X)+AppleWebKit/534.46+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/5.1+Mobile/9B206+Safari/7534.48.3

Answer (score 0):

We faced similar issue recently. We were able to fix it by adding "Allow HEAD" to the protected resource in siteminder. We are using siteminder for authentication/authorization.  You may want to check if 'HEAD' is allowed in apache for the protected resource.